# TypeORM Error initialising the Database -- TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Database')

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, node.js-typeorm, ionic7

I use TypeORM to wrap my database. In my Angular Ionic 7 app I initialise the database the following in my AppComponent but receive an error during the initialisation in the platform browser.

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(async () => {
      if (platform.is('cordova')) {
        // Running on device or emulator
        const appDataSource = new DataSource({
          type: 'cordova',
          database: 'test',
          location: 'default',
          logging: ['error', 'query', 'schema'],
          synchronize: true,
          entities: [Person],
        });
        try {
          appDataSource.initialize();
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      } else {
        // Running app in browser
        const appDataSource = new DataSource({
          type: 'sqljs',
          autoSave: true,
          location: 'browser',
          logging: ['error', 'query', 'schema'],
          synchronize: true,
          entities: [Person],
        });
        try {
          appDataSource.initialize();
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

The entity Person looks like this:

```
@Entity('person')
export class Person {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  firstName: string;

  @Column()
  lastName: string;
}
```

I get the following error message:

```
main.ts:11 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Database')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Database')
at SqljsDriver.js:214:52
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:3:1)
at _next (asyncToGenerator.js:22:1)
at asyncToGenerator.js:27:1
at new ZoneAwarePromise (zone.js:1411:21)
at asyncToGenerator.js:19:1
at SqljsDriver.createDatabaseConnectionWithImport (SqljsDriver.js:225:40)
at SqljsDriver.js:99:33
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:1193:31)
at zone.js:1100:17
at zone.js:1116:33
at asyncGeneratorStep (asyncToGenerator.js:6:1)
at _throw (asyncToGenerator.js:25:1)
at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:368:26)
at Object.onInvoke (core.mjs:27450:33)
at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:367:52)
at Zone.run (zone.js:129:43)
at zone.js:1257:36
```

What can I do to fix this Problem?
I use:
"typescript": 4.9.3
"@angular/core": 16.0.0

Answer (score 0):

hfs23!
You have two possible DataSource. I think your call is using the "else" Datasource because it don't have a the database node, but it needs a confirmation.
By the way, What's the line 11 in the main.ts?

Try to add database in "else DataSource"

```js
// Running app in browser 
const appDataSource = new DataSource({ 
type: 'sqljs', 
database: '<The raw UInt8Array database that should be imported>',
autoSave: true, 
location: 'browser', 
logging: ['error', 'query', 'schema'], 
synchronize: true, 
entities: [Person], 
});
```

Comment: Line 11 of main.ts is the following:
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

Comment: How can I give the confirmation?

Comment: @hfs23, With the needs a confirmation I mean it needs a test. I was thinking if you put a database node in this else:
``` typescript
// Running app in browser
        const appDataSource = new DataSource({
          type: 'sqljs',
          database: 'database_name'
          autoSave: true,
          location: 'browser',
          logging: ['error', 'query', 'schema'],
          synchronize: true,
          entities: [Person],
        });
```

Comment: I edited on my main answer.

Comment: I don't really understand what this UInt8Array database is that should be imported. Could you please give me an example?

Comment: @hfs23, I think is some reference of your pre existent database (if you have one) according [sqljs doc](https://github.com/sql-js/sql.js#usage) and [TypeORM](https://typeorm.io/data-source-options#sqljs-data-source-options). But if you don't have one, I'd debug [this part of the typeORM](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/driver/sqljs/SqljsDriver.ts#L279). It's exactly your message error. On GitHub it's at L279, in my project it's at L215, in yours it's probably at L215 like in your message error.

Comment: (...) It's expecting a "Database" node from this.sqlite.Database, but this node may not exist. This sqlite node is fed in [loadDependencies](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/driver/sqljs/SqljsDriver.ts#L297) but it shouldn't be assigning something like { Database:"" }. I got to this part but it's difficult move on without the project. But I think if you put a console.log in this part you can see the problem.